# How to evaluate Gaussian Process Latent Variable Model¶

Tags: python, pyro, gaussian-process

I am following a tutorial on Gaussian Process Latent Variable Model  here is the link https://pyro.ai/examples/gplvm.html

It is a dimension-reduction method.
Now I want to evaluate the model and find the accuracy, confusion matrix is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please, make the question self-contained, by putting all relevant code here, state what you have already tried and try to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found my answer. I have to make a model that takes the transformed data (dimension-reduced data) as input. After training this model I can evaluate the model.